# How to get file from django-import-export?

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-import-export

I want to use groupby() function from pandas, but dont know how to get file before export.
I've tried dehydrate, but I dont  think it's what i want.

```
    phone = Field()
    class Meta:
        model = Phones
        # exclude = ('id', )
    def dehydrate_url(self,phone):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get hold of the file data before import, it is easy, just use the [before_import()](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_resources.html#import_export.resources.Resource.before_export) method:

This needs to be declared in your Resource, for example:

```py
class BookResource(resources.ModelResource):

    def before_import(self, dataset, using_transactions, dry_run, **kwargs):
        for row in dataset.dict:
            print(row)
```